# Downloading file from Java servlet gives null

Tags: java, file, servlets, stream

I am trying to create a method that allows users to download a file on the file system via a Servlet. Right now, the correct `filename` shows on the download and a file is downloaded but the contents of the file are always null.

I've also tried to get the file contents to print to the console but nothing is showing up.

Can anyone suggest what I've done wrong here?

Thanks

```
String filePath = "uploads/" + request.getParameter( "filename" );
File downloadFile = new File( filePath );

String relativePath = getServletContext().getRealPath( "" );
System.out.println( "relativePath = " + relativePath );

ServletContext context = getServletContext();

String mimeType = context.getMimeType( filePath );
if( mimeType == null )
{
    mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
}
System.out.println( "MIME type: " + mimeType );

response.setContentType( mimeType );
response.setContentLength( (int) downloadFile.length() );

String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
String headerValue = String.format( "attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName() );
response.setHeader( headerKey, headerValue );
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes( downloadFile.getAbsoluteFile().toPath() );
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

System.out.println( bytes.toString() );

outStream.write( bytes );

outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

**Annotations**

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns =
{ "/Routing/*" })
@MultipartConfig(location = "/tmp", fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024,     maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5, maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5 * 5)
public class Routing extends HttpServlet
{
```

Comment: did you check the file path... try to print downloadFile.getpath() and see whether it is giving correct absoutle path where your target file exists

Comment: @PavanKumarK thanks, yes the path is correct and i've done downloadFile.exists() which returns true also.

Comment: Which Servlet version are you using? Secondly, which Servlet container are you running your Servlet? Thirdly, show us your Servlet configuration file where you registered your Servlet (either in `web.xml` or using annotations `@WebServlet`).

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Hi I have added my annotations to the question. I am running Apache Tomcat/7.0.59, JVM 1.7.0_75-b13, web app version 2.4. Does that help?

Comment: You used the **exact** code from [this site](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-download-file-example) right?

Comment: Is `byte[] bytes` not null? Have you debugged it to see if there are content?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I did follow an online tutorial but it wasn't working, so I've changed some of the code so its not exactly the same. bytes.toString() is printing out [B@1494a86

Comment: Printing out new String( bytes, "UTF-8" ) is showing the content of the file, but the downloaded file still contains null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is a modified solution from BalusC [File Servlet blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html).

The reason I use this solution is because it `reset()` the `HttpServletResponse response` before writing data.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns =
{ "/Routing/*" })
@MultipartConfig(location = "/tmp", fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024,     maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5, maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5 * 5)
public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    // Constants ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240; // 10KB.


    // Actions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        // Get requested file by path info.
        String filePath = "uploads/" + request.getParameter( "filename" );

        // Check if file is actually supplied to the request URI.
        if (filePath == null) {
            // Do your thing if the file is not supplied to the request URI.
            // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning page, or just ignore it.
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
            return;
        }

        // Decode the file name (might contain spaces and on) and prepare file object.
        File downloadFile = new File( filePath );

        // Check if file actually exists in filesystem.
        if (!downloadFile.exists()) {
            // Do your thing if the file appears to be non-existing.
            // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning page, or just ignore it.
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
            return;
        }

        // Get content type by filename.
        String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName());

        // If content type is unknown, then set the default value.
        // For all content types, see: http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp
        // To add new content types, add new mime-mapping entry in web.xml.
        if (contentType == null) {
            contentType = "application/octet-stream";
        }

        // Init servlet response.
        response.reset();
        response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");

        // Prepare streams.
        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;

        try {
            // Open streams.
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

            // Write file contents to response.
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes( downloadFile.getAbsoluteFile().toPath() );
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytes.length);
        } finally {
            // Gently close streams.
            close(output);
            close(input);
        }
    }

    // Helpers (can be refactored to public utility class) ----------------------------------------

    private static void close(Closeable resource) {
        if (resource != null) {
            try {
                resource.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Do your thing with the exception. Print it, log it or mail it.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: adding the response.reset() like your answer had resolved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Please remember to accept the answer that worked for you/

Answer (score 2):

I recommend several tests to isolate the problem since there are still too many unknowns here. I had no problems running your code, so it is likely a configuration issue with your servlet container, or an assumption about the filesystem.

The key to isolating the problem is start with the basics. Try to return a String instead of a file, to ensure that the communication with the server is actually behaving properly. If you get the same response, then you know the problem isn't with the file IO:

```
byte[] bytes = "This is a test.".getBytes();
int contentLength = bytes.length;
String mimeType = "text/plain";

response.setContentType( mimeType );
response.setContentLength( contentLength );
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
outStream.write( bytes );
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

If the above test worked, then you know the problem is with the file or the method you are using to read the file. You code currently makes a lot of assumptions about everything being perfect with the file that is being requested. Perform some rigorous testing to make certain the file is accessible:

```
int fileSize = downloadFile.length();
System.out.println("File path: " + downloadFile.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("exists: " + downloadFile.exists());
System.out.println("canRead: " + downloadFile.canRead());
System.out.println("File size: " + fileSize);
```

and finally check the file size reported by the filesystem against the number of bytes that were read:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes( downloadFile.getAbsoluteFile().toPath() );
int bytesRead = bytes.length;
System.out.println("bytes read: " + bytesRead);
```

The results of these tests should narrow down the problem for you.

Comment: I have tried your first test with "This is a test.".getBytes() but when I navigate to the page it is blank. Is this a problem with my servlet container? Thanks

Comment: @FMC This is quite possibly a container configuration issue. At this point, I recommend going back to the example web applications provided with Tomcat and make certain those are working first.

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me debug the problem. Adding response.reset() to the start of the method resolved the issue. I think it may be because I already had an open PrintWriter from a previous action in the servlet. I've given the answer to Buhake because their answer had the reset method that fixed it. +1 for your help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the file is empty add this line to make sure the file is not empty

```
System.out.println("File size: " + bytes.length);
```

Comment: File size: 3 - the contents of the file after downloading are "nul"

Answer (score 0):

Just add 
outStream.setContentLength(inStream.available);
after outStream.write( bytes );

Comment: [InputStream.available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking.  It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.